# Evidence of rustproofing

Tags: rust

How to do find evidence of rustproofing done on the bottom of a car? We are talking rustproofing done with "grease" / "oil" techniques at regular garages. What should I expect to see after rustproofing has been done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look under your car, you'll be able to feel it because it will have a texture to it. You'll probably also see areas where there is over spray from it. You'll see this on mufflers or exhaust pipes because most of the time when it's sprayed on, it's done pretty quickly and very willy-nilly (all over the place).

Rust-proofing (or undercoating) isn't *grease* or *oil* based, it is a coating, not unlike Linex you'd put in the bed of a truck. The main difference is, it won't be as thick. It is a rubberized coating which helps protect from the road-nastiness. While it is billed as "rust-proof", it just prolongs it from happening. Sooner or later, the rust-proofing will come off and there you go. When I say "come off", I'm saying it basically peels off. This takes many years after it is applied. For the most part, it works pretty well.

You can apply your own undercoating if you so desire. Companies such as Eastwood has products available which will allow you to do such.

Comment: Thank you! The garage we went to was specialized in rust-proofing and according to the owner, they used "canola oil", whatever that means. Afterwards, we had a pretty strong smell of that "substance" inside and around the car until it evaporated.

Comment: The "specialized" garage said they themselves use canola oil, or the "specialized" garage said whomever had applied it for you had applied canola oil ... I cannot believe a garage would admit to it, so I'll take it you meant the latter, lol.

Comment: They said it themselves. Is there something to be concerned about? It cost 100$. Edit: it was what one would call a "mainstream" place, with professional installations, not some neighborhood garage.

Comment: Wow ... I could spend $5 on Canola oil and splash it up on the under side of vehicles and call it rustproofing ... Charge a $100 for it and make money all day long! Woot! There is nothing to worry about if you are worried about adverse effects. There will be nothing left of it the next time you go through a rain storm, though, or get the underside of your car cleaned. What I would suggest to you is to find some online (like at Eastwood) and do some spraying yourself. It will probably cost you another $100, but this time it will stay and it will actually be coated.

Comment: Alright thanks, I will keep this in mind next time :)